# How to temporarily change locale for sudo?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, locale

To change the locale of the current user like `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

But this environment variable doesn't affect the root user. When I use `sudo` the display language remains default.

How can I temporarily change locale for using `sudo`?

`sudo export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` didn't work, probably that is a `bash` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` sanitizes environment before running any command, so unless you save the desired environment variable in `/etc/sudoers` using `env_keep` the varible will not be preserved by `sudo`.

Alternately, for a single command, you can do:

```
sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 some_command
```

In order to preserve the current environment:

```
sudo -E some_command
```