# How to temporarily change locale for a gui-command?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gui, locale

If I try this [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278861/how-to-temporarily-change-locale-for-sudo) with a gui-command like `sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 partitionmanager`, it's ends up with some confusing hints I can't get.

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
kf.dbusaddons: DBus session bus not found. To circumvent this problem try the 
following command (with bash):
export $(dbus-launch)


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 apt search kdesudo gksudo
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

Why this don't work for me? Is there something like `gksudo`in **[Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425620/sudo-gksudo-kdesudo-and-their-differences)** for **Debian**?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: none of these warnings are related to your setting of the locale, but with you running a graphical program through sudo

Comment: What Marcus said. Also, is there actually a problem? Does `partitionmanager` actually launch or not? Did you try the suggestion from the error message? Does that fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately `partitionmanager` doesn't launch this way. Of course, I am able to launch it as usual.

Comment: And, yes, I executed `export $(dbus-launch)`.